# Можно ли как-то повторить технлогию files on-demand?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Может быть уже существуют какие-то библиотеки позволяющие сделать "файлы по запросу", или может быть подкинете идей как можно прийти к похожему функционалу?

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Есть webdav, например

Comment: Хочется сделать как в onedrive, или хотя бы приблизиться к этому, ведь это весьма интересно реализованно у них, и хотелось бы разобраться

Comment: `Owncloud`\ `Nextcloud`?